# Issue with progress bar thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I created a small GUI using Tkinter. It has a button on click of which some data is written to Excel.

To show the progress, I added a progress bar but since the process is resource intensive, the progress bar appears only at the end. Therefore, I used threading as shown.

In the Main function below, I initialized the progress bar in a different thread but I want to update the current value of the task in Start function.

Because of this line:

```
progressbar.Start()
```

it is just continuously running without anything to do with the current progress.

```
def Start():
    x = 0
    progressbar["value"] = x
    for idx, val in enumerate(rows):
      region_url = val[1]

      if (model_url != '-'):
        url = 'http://testurl/' + region_url 

        x = x + 1
        if (x > 4):
            break

# Main          
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    window = Tk()
    new = progress(window)

    # Add a grid
    mainframe = Frame(window)
    mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    mainframe.pack(pady = 100 , padx = 150)

    # DropDown
    popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *regionList)
    Label(mainframe, text="Region").grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    # Button
    btnSubmit = Button(mainframe, text= "Execute",command=StartScrap).grid(row = 2, column = 18)
    popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =0)

    # Progress Bar
    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient = HORIZONTAL,length=300, mode = 'indeterminate')
    progressbar.pack()
    t = threading.Thread()
    progressbar["maximum"] = 4
    progressbar.start()
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things in your code that needs fixing.

Firstly you defined the function `Start` which controls how your progressbar is updated, but you never call it.

Secondly, you define the progressbar mode as `indeterminate` and that just `start` the progress bar - it works but it will just periodically move the progressbar.

Thirdly, you defined the Thread `t` but never put a target function.

Here's how to move your progressbar in a thread:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

def Start():
    def update_pbar():
        for i in range(5): #replace this with your method to update your progressbar
            time.sleep(1)
            progressbar["value"] = i
    t = threading.Thread(target=update_pbar)
    t.start()

# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()

    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient = HORIZONTAL,length=300, mode = 'determinate')
    progressbar.pack()
    progressbar["maximum"] = 4
    btnSubmit = Button(window, text="Execute", command=Start).pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It is working. But one small issue left is that it starts immediately when I execute the application. In my code sample above, it should start when btnSubmit button is clicked. I changed target=btnSubmit, but it just shows the final progress at the end not incremental, even though btnSubmit is calling Start

Comment: You can have your button to start the thread directly by `command=t.start`. However you can only click the button once since it will raise a `RuntimeError` if you try to start the same thread multiple times - I have edited my snippet so you can start as many times as you like.

Comment: I tried the code. Though progress bar appears after sometime but the GUI title shows "Not Responding".

Comment: Do you mean the GUI is not responding in the above code, or after you modified it to your own version?

Comment: Yes, on GUI, the window title has message (Not responding). This issue was previously also and even after the changes.